# Android SDK error in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I run the eclipse from the SDK folder, before start creating a class. this error appears, and I
don't understand it:

```
[2014-05-30 18:37:35 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Arnold\.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\Arnold\.android\devices.xml.old
cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'nodpi' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

How do I fix it?.

Comment: Download a fresh copy of the SDK and eclipse. Something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error few weeks ago. Download actual copy of the SDK and try to remove all your metadata from your workspace folder or set up new one. In my case it works.

Answer (score 0):

I went tot the

C:\Users*YOUR NAME HERE*\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images

and removed the api (in my case android-23) that threw the error, worked for me.